# schedule canvas drawing

Tags: android, canvas, schedule

I'm using canvas to draw some circles, then, after some seconds, I need to change the color of one, so, I will need to invalidate the circle, and redraw it with a different color.
I don't understand how to achieve this, throw Handler, because I have an error.

```
public class PagesIndicatorsSchermata extends View{
    Paint Circle1 = new Paint();
    Paint Circle2 = new Paint();


    int tempo = 1000;
    Paint WhiteDot = new Paint();

    public PagesIndicatorsSchermata(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {

    final    int height = getHeight();
    final    int width = getWidth() /2;
    final     int widhtRindicators = width + (width*4/100);
    final    int widhtLindicators = width - (width*4/100);
    final    int heightindicators = (height * 80)/100;

        //indicatori pagina
        Circle1.setAntiAlias(true);
        Circle1.setColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"));
        canvas.drawCircle(widhtRindicators, heightindicators, 9  , Circle1);

        Circle2.setAntiAlias(true);
        Circle2.setColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"));
        canvas.drawCircle(widhtLindicators, heightindicators, 9 , Circle2);


        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                WhiteDot.setAntiAlias(true);
                WhiteDot.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                canvas.drawCircle(widhtRindicators, heightindicators, 9 , WhiteDot);

            }
        }, tempo);

        super.onDraw(canvas);

    }
}
```

I have this error:

> A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x128 in tid
>   16461

the app starts, and then, after a second it stops

Don't know to solve, or alternative methods to draw canvas at scheduled time.

Comment: I also have this problem. Did you ever find a fix?